# kindle sdcard access while usb debugging

Tags: android, debugging, usb, sd-card, kindle-fire

When I debug on Kindle Fire, my app has no read/write access to /sdcard and other Android apps (ASTRO) too. On other Android devices I do not see this problem. It seems to work fine when usb is disconnected, but how can I debug it?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure about Kindle, but other Android devices have different USB modes, e.g. "Charge only", "PC Mode", "Media Mode" etc.  Some of these modes make the SD card appear as a USB disk to the PC and **disappear** from the device, other modes do not.  There's usually a notification that allows you to choose the mode.

Comment: This is not a novice question. Looks that Kindle is a different beast. I could not find any ways to control its usb mode. It allows debugging by default and the desktop/laptop recognizes it as soon as you modify your computer's settings to enable debugging.